# Unable to install package "retrying" in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, installation

I am using Ubuntu and I have a code which needs to install various libraries. I mostly use python2.7, but due to some libraries this code uses, I had to move to python3, these libraries are

**import urllib.request

import urllib.parse

import urllib.error**

But then there was one library import which I could not import in python3, after searching on Google, I found that moving to python3.7 will solve the issue, and it did solve. Import was
**from json import JSONDecodeError**

But now I have the issue of **'from retrying import retry'**......After installing it with pip and pip3, I could import it in Python2.7 and python3, but I am failing to import it in python3.7.....

So, basically I am jumping across python versions to import the libraries required to run the code of an ex company employee....Please guide me how to import "retrying" in python3.7 or any way I can just install all the below ones in one python version

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from json import JSONDecodeError
from retrying import retry

Answer (score 1):

I installed python3.5, and everything worked fine in it. Weird it did not work in python3.7, anyways my issue is resolved.